# Stopping nosey people on Facebook

Tags: privacy, facebook

I thought I would ask this question here as it as to do with security. There are a few people on my Facebook that are close to me in real life. I don't mind it in real life (considering my real life is boring), but they seem to want to know every detail about everything I post on Facebook. One person ALWAYS comments on something I post and says something like "me too", "why?", or something totally unrelated to what I posted. Then there are some (including my mom) who will constantly monitor my Facebook and the moment I post something, they'll call or text me right away about it. If I put these people on ignore, then they notice and literally force me to take them off my ignore list. Maybe this social media is getting in the way of my privacy and maybe I like to be drama free, but is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: You assert that this has to do with security. How? What exactly are you in danger of? Keeping bad company?

Comment: I think you should ask your question here http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't use facebook.

Comment: "me too", "why?"

Comment: How is this question related to information security? Would you kindly care to explain?

Comment: [This link might help you](https://www.facebook.com/help/delete_account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option "Who should see this?".
As far as I know, changing that to custom and including someone, as you've mentioned here, your mom into "Don't share this", you can avoid getting monitored. For that commenting thing, you can choose to share only close friends, or like above, choose custom list.

I guess, that's the only way